# Getting the hours that should be removed from the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a generated array(let's say $timeList) from my API server that generates the following code:

```
Array(
[0](
['Time'] => 14:00
['DisplayTime'] => "2pm"
)
[1](
['Time'] => 15:00
['DisplayTime'] => "3pm"
)
[2](
['Time'] => 16:00
['DisplayTime'] => "4pm"
)
[3](
['Time'] => 17:00
['DisplayTime'] => "5pm"
)
[4](
['Time'] => 18:00
['DisplayTime'] => "6pm"
)
)
```

Apparently I need to be able to compare it with the array($timeBlock) that I am getting from the database, which is this:

```
Array(
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [BlockedDate] => 2016-10-28
            [StartTime] => 15:00:00
            [EndTime] => 17:00:00
        ))
```

Is there a way for me to compare the list that I am getting from the API with the blocked time?

I have tried the following, but it would rather be nonsensical:

```
foreach($timeList $index => $value)
for($x = 0; $x < 24;$x++){
     //supposedly loop here the per hour value
   // compare the time by $x:00 == to my list's time
        unset($timeList[$index]);
}
```

But I immediately realized I cannot do it if the time given to me is not an exact hour. So I am stuck with what to do to be able to cycle through the array and still hitting the mark for the start and end times.

Comment: I answered but realized I not fully answered to your question. Can you add more details about what is your expected result ? (the cycle & the mark start/End) (I will complete my answer with your inputs)

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions to compare date:

1. Create yourself a value based on the content. Ex: h:m:s is separated by ':'. So, split and make: h*3600 + m*60 + s.
2. Use date/hour comparaison library or funtions

Functions: [datetime](http://php.net/datetime.diff) or [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

An example:

```
<?php foreach( $timeList as $index => $value ) {
  for($x = 0; $x < 24; $x++){
    if( strtotime($value['Time']) == strtotime($x . ':00') ) {
      echo $value['DisplayTime'];
    }
  }
}
```

Here on the loop i create a time (1:00, 2:00, ... 24:00) and compare with the tileList value

Another example - take only the hour:

```
<?php foreach( $timeList as $index => $value ) {
  for($x = 0; $x < 24; $x++){
    if( strstr($value['Time'], ':', true) == $x ) { // If hour = 1/2/3/.../24
      echo $value['DisplayTime'];
    }
  }
}
```

> The code `strstr('a:b:c', ':', true)` will return the value before the first `:` => `a`. In your case, the hour.

Comment: its just a numerical comparison, there no need to consider thea values as actual time